# Getting cURL server response and printing it in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, parsing, curl

I have a script which uploads a file to server using cURL in PHP and I need to print or save to file the response for testing purposes (in final, I'll parse the output, but that's not what I want to say).

I have the following code:

```
<?php
include 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html = file_get_html('http://uloz.to/upload');
$form = $html->find('form[id=form_upload_nginx]', 0);
$adress = $form->getAttribute('action');

//echo 'Successfully parsed adress';
echo $adress;

$ch = curl_init();
$file = 'C:\some-file.jpg';
$data = array('upfile_0' => "@$file");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $adress);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$out = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo '<p>';
echo strip_tags($out);
echo '</p>';
?>
```

And server response should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Redirect</title>
        <script>
            document.domain = document.domain.split('.').slice(-2).join('.');
            top.upload.onUploadCompleted('http://ulozto.net/done.php?rnd_id=419737883238269087&fileid=59286012&rt=&p_hash=&token=c603931da2fc2fba807accf205954e45');
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now I want to get the server response and use it in the script, but the first problem is that I can't really check if the file has beeen uploaded, as the server usually can't find file I uploaded by name (but the file was almost every time uploaded successfully and found on the server, so let's say the upload works). And the second thing is that output of cURL is empty.

I'm newbie in using cURL in PHP and all those things are little bit confusing for me, can someone point me to the right way?

Comment: Do you control the server?  If so, can we see the server code that handles the upload?  Your statement "the server usually cant find the file I uploaded by name" is confusing to me.  The server should't need to "find" anything.  The file is passed in to it.  As far as your second question, the `$out` variable will contain the response from the server.  If `$out` is blank, then that means the server returned nothing.  It is probably more likely that `$out` is FALSE, which means the request failed.  Check if that is the case with `if ($out === false) { die("upload failed";)}`.

Comment: It's public file storage like Mega, but you can also search through its content. When you upload the file, it takes about five minutes to access this file using search, that's why I'm not able to see the result realtime. But using search on the server I found out that the upload itself works (I upload the same file, but with unique name, so I can see which code works), only probably cURL don't get the response or I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: I took the server response from command-line cURL, so I'm 99% sure that it should look like it.

Comment: @EvandelaCruz You can see the form itself and test it on www.uloz.to/upload